# Bash Print between two matches

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I've got a file that reads like this, on a single line.

```
"ID":"1234","NAME":"Person","OWNER":"Dave"
```

I need to just output the value of ID Using Awk, Sed or Grep or something like it.

IE I just need the output to be

```
1234
```

Catch is it could be anywhere in the file, so it has to MATCH "ID" and print "1234"

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Your input looks as if there is a double quote missing.

Comment: yes there was, added back in now